# Chrome devtools extension send message from background to currently open tab only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a Chrome Devtools extension and my flow is pretty basic:

- Click button on panel, send message to background
- Background receives message, sends message to content script
- Content script receives message, executes javascript, sends message back on completion
- Background script receives messages, sends message to **all instances of my open devtools extension.**

The problem is, I only want to send the message to the tab/instance of devtools that sent the request, not all currently open devtools instances.

Here's my devtools.js ( it's mostly copy/paste from another example, and I'll give credit in a comment after I find it again ):

```
    chrome.devtools.panels.create('Test', '/icon.png', '/panel.html', function(extensionPanel) {
    var _window; // Going to hold the reference to panel.html's `window`

    var data = [];
    var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'fav'});
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        // Write information to the panel, if exists.
        // If we don't have a panel reference (yet), queue the data.
        if (_window) {
            if(msg.type && msg.type === 'taborder_list') {
                _window.fav.receive_taborder(msg);
            } else {
                _window.fav.receive_request(msg);
            }

        } else {
            data.push(msg);
        }
    });

    extensionPanel.onShown.addListener(function tmp(panelWindow) {
        extensionPanel.onShown.removeListener(tmp); // Run once only
        _window = panelWindow;

        // Release queued data
        var msg;
        while (msg = data.shift()) 
            _window.fav.receive_request(msg);
        // Just to show that it's easy to talk to pass a message back:
        _window.respond = function(msg) {
            port.postMessage(msg);
        };
    });
});
```

And here's my background.js:

```
var ports = [];
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    if (port.name !== "fav") return;
    ports.push(port);
    // Remove port when destroyed (eg when devtools instance is closed)
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
        var i = ports.indexOf(port);
        if (i !== -1) ports.splice(i, 1);
            chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win) {
                chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs) {
                    var activeTab;
                    $(tabs).each(function(i,v) {
                        if(v.active === true) {
                            activeTab = tabs[i]['id'];
                        }
                    });
                    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(activeTab, {greeting: 'all_off'});
                });
            });      
    });
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        // Received message from devtools. Do something:
        console.log('Received message from devtools page', msg);

        chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win) {
            chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs) {
                var activeTab;
                $(tabs).each(function(i,v) {
                    if(v.active === true) {
                        activeTab = tabs[i]['id'];
                    }
                });
                chrome.tabs.sendRequest(activeTab, msg)
            });
        });
    });
});
// Function to send a message to all devtools.html views:
function notifyDevtools(msg) {
    ports.forEach(function(port) {
        port.postMessage(msg);
    });
}

function listen_from_content(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    ports.forEach(function(port) {
        port.postMessage(request);
    });
    sendResponse('hello');
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(listen_from_content);
```

I realize that there is a forEach in there, which is why it's sending the message to each tab, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to only send it to the requesting panel.

And finally, here is the way that I'm sending messages from my panel to the background:

```
respond({name: 'fav', greeting: 'analyze'});
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

I ended up looping through the open windows, and assigning each port with it's tab ID.

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win) {
  var activeTab;
  $(tabs).each(function(i,v) {
    if(v.active === true) {
      activeTab = tabs[i]['id'];
    }
  ports.activeTab = activeTab;
  ports.push(port);
});
```

This is in my background.js, on the "chrome.runtime.onConnect" method.

Comment: See [Restricting communication with selected tabId in chrome-extension development](//stackoverflow.com/a/42681111)

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  It didn't work with my code, but it set me on the right path.  Posting my code above.